# I am unable to assign elders and co-leaders, and I am the leader of the clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When I am under the clan tab, I click on the person to promote. I do not get the option to promote to elder. Therefore, I am unable to assign co-leaders.

Comment: Could you please make a screenshot of this and attach it?

Comment: It's been 3 months and no screenshot...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot promote, demote, or kick out members of your clan while viewing another village. If you still cannot promote in your own village, then something is wrong.